# How to change the entity validation warning in Guidewire ClaimCenter 10

Tags: guidewire, gosu

When ClaimCenter validates Forms and the entities, it displays the Entityname within the Warnmessage.

Is there a way to change the behaviour that the Entity Name is not shown to the user?

Comment: go to the warning message, change the trigger logic, or If u want to change the Entityname, go to Entitynames in-studio change the return statement.

Comment: I don't want to change the Entityname. We need them in our Logfiles, but the user should not see the EntityName on the GUI

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the below code ,

LocationUtil.addRequestScopedInfoMessage(“Display your warning message here”)

I hope it helps you. If not, please share the screen shot of your warning message and the validation logic.